# PHP natsort() with accented letters

Tags: php, sorting, locale, natsort

I'm trying to sort an array like this

```
['České Budějovice',
 'Cidlina',
 'Praha 1',
 'Praha 10',
 'Praha 4']
```

in a natural way. The result should be

```
['Cidlina',
 'České Budějovice',
 'Praha 1',
 'Praha 4',
 'Praha 10']
```

The natsort() function itself does a great job sorting in a natural way (i.e. putting 'Praha 10' after 'Praha 4') but it puts the words that start with accented letters at the end.

Is there a way how to sort naturally while respecting the locale?

Comment: You could try using [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) with the `SORT_LOCALE_STRING` and `SORT_NATURAL` flags instead of `natsort()`, and the appropriate locale setting (`cs_CS`)

Comment: Unfortunately, Collator can't do natural sort and sort() doesn't work with SORT_LOCALE_STRING http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7254dbbdea400b4acc404f3bd8d7c345b2e78232

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** with [`natsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php).

In [project page](http://sourcefrog.net/projects/natsort/) you will find this:

> Comparison of characters is purely numeric, without taking character set or locale into account. So it is only correct for ASCII.

Comment: I think you're right. After researching, I don't think there's an easy way to do that other than creating own comparison function.